# An exercise in "Number Theory" by Shafarevich and Borevich

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

I have trouble in solving a basic exercise of the book *Number Theory* by Shafarevich and Borevich. It is exercise 4, chapter 1, page 4 in my edition.

It goes as follows: Using the properties of the Legendre-Symbol, show that the congruence
$$(x^2-13)(x^2-17)(x^2-221) \equiv 0 \mod m$$
is solvable for all $m$.

I know how to deal with the problem if $m$ is a prime. However, I don't know what to do if $m$ is a power of a prime. (I also know that solving the problem for all prime powers suffices.)

Comment: Hensel's lemma is the key to lifting congruences mod p to higher powers of p.

Comment: @Merosity, thanks for the hint but the book did not mention Hensel's lemma yet. So, I am not sure if this is the solution the authors have in mind.

Comment: Same idea as in the linked dupe (there are also many other dupes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that if neither of $13$ or $17$ are a quadratic residue $\mod p^n$ then $13 \cdot 17 = 221$ must be a quadratic residue (this follows from the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$ being cyclic for odd $p$ and you need to consider the case $p = 2$ separately)

Comment: Thanks. I see how it works. However, with your approach, I do not really need the Legendre-Symbol at all. Do you have any idea what the authors with their proposal "use the properties of the Legendre-Symbol" might had in mind?

Comment: That would be another way of proving that the product of two quadratic non-residues is a quadratic residue